# How to move iframe behind on div? css

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, vimeo

How can we move the iframe behind the div.

Here an sample below, I want to show "custom_title" div in front of the *iframe*.
It's initially showing but when we click the fullscreen, the "custom_title" div eventually gone.

Someone knows how to achieve this? I have here the [codepen](https://codepen.io/escbooster12/pen/rNmpdVx)

> Note: fullscreen icon does not display in the snippet, i don't know why. But you check out the codepen.

```css
.title_container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 10%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/347119375?color=ef2200&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="true" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" title="0vid1.mp4" data-ready="true"></iframe>
   <div class="title_container">Custom Title</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you want to achieve in a bit more detail? I understood that you want the div to be shown when the video is in fullscreen? Is that correct?

Comment: @QuentinAlbert I want to float custom controls e.g. play/pause buttons. just like youtube. In order to achieve it. I must know at least how to do it in simple text and white background.

Comment: Will it work if you wrap the iframe in an div too and then usng css style attribute index?

Comment: @Reporter it does not work sir.

Answer (score 0):

Fullscreen move pulls the video out of the document for the purposes of rendering. This leaves the text you positioned on top of it behind.

To achieve this you would need to make the **div** fullscreen and not the video (and then you'd need to format the video appropriately to get it to full the div).

I doubt you can override Vimeo's button to achieve that, so you'd need to add your own.

Comment: sorry. can I see some example or reference. or atleast just a simple plain text that floats in fullscreen mode. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

**Full Screen option is disabled below so that Users use the button to make the `iframe` full screen.**
To make the `iframe` full screen and show the `div` you can use:
**Note**: **Try saving and running the code locally on your device as Stack Overflow's compiler is facing issues runnning it.**

```js
//https://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/o5njka95/6/

function requestFullScreen(element) {
    // Supports most browsers and their versions.
    var requestMethod = element.requestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || element.msRequestFullscreen;

    if (requestMethod) { // Native full screen.
        requestMethod.call(element);
    } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") { // Older IE.
        var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        if (wscript !== null) {
            wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
        }
    }
}

function makeFullScreen() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].className = "fullScreen";
    var elem = document.body;
    requestFullScreen(elem);
}
```

```css
.title_container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 10%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
button{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 20%;
}
iframe.fullScreen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
<!-- Full Sceen option is disabled-->
   <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/347119375?color=ef2200&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" disablefullscreen  style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" title="0vid1.mp4" data-ready="true"></iframe>
   <div class="title_container">Custom Title</div>
</div>
<button onclick="makeFullScreen()">Make Full Screen</button>
```

Or you can `disable` the `controls` and use the [`Vimeo Player.js`](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js) to add more functionalities and I ,also, think that the problem can be solved without hiding the full-screen option and using the button to make the `iframe` full screen, by the `Vimeo Player.js`, but that was complicated, so, you can try, but I am not sure.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid specifically in this case there is no way to achieve this, because of how `fullscreen` api is working. If you want `some-element` to display in fullscreen mode you need this `some-element` to be inside of DOM element which is displaying in fullscreen.

In your case you need `.title_container` to be inside vimeo player's element, but you could not put it inside `iframe` unless there is no specific `api` to do this.

Read more about fullscreen on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API/Guide

Simple example of how it can be done by adding custom fullscreen button.

**Try to run on your local environment, fullscreen seems to be not working on stackoverflow:**

```js
let $btn = document.querySelector('#toggle'),
  $iframe = document.querySelector('iframe'),
  $video = document.querySelector('#video');


$btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (document.fullscreenElement) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
    return;
  }
  $video.requestFullscreen();
})


document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', (event) => {
  if (document.fullscreenElement) {
    $btn.innerHTML = 'Exit fullscreen'
  } else {
    $btn.innerHTML = 'Fullscreen'
  }
});
```

```css
#video {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
}

#video:fullscreen iframe {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.title_container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 10%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

#video:fullscreen button {
  position: absolute;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  right: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div id='video'>
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/347119375?color=ef2200&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; picture-in-picture" title="0vid1.mp4" data-ready="true"></iframe>
  <div class="title_container">Custom Title</div>
  <button id='toggle'>Fullscreen</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I added "vimeo" tag in the description. For the meantime, i'll do my own research for api, lets see if someone has their own solution for this. if none I'll mark this as answer.

Comment: @gecko I did not noticed 'vimeo tag', I've added simple example of how it can be done on your own.

Comment: i tried your latest update. does it does fullscreen (entire page) or fullscreen (entire screen)? And how to exit fullscreen? I click the vimeos fullscreen icon. it removes the text floating.

Comment: @gecko only `#video` element and all its siblings enters fullscreen mode. Vimeo player has nothing to do with this. If you choose to develop fullscreen mode by your own, then you should remove fullscreen button from Vimeo player and implement it by yourself. You could exit fullscreen mode by pressing 'Escape` or by pressing button one more time - I've updated the example check it out